# What is web methods

Tags: web, webmethod

What exactly is web methods?Is it a language,a framework or application or purely a company responsible for integration of application,that is, providing a framework to achieve integration.

Please give a brief.
Thanks

Answer (score 7):

There are a few very different things this term brings to mind:

- The .NET [WebMethodAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.webmethodattribute%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)
- Java [WebMethod annotation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/jws/WebMethod.html)
- The Software AG [webMethods product](http://www.softwareag.com/uk/products/wm/default.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Not a language, as far as I know.

Web services have methods that you can call - REST or SOAP or RPC-XML.  You can implement those in lots of languages.

There's an EAI server called [webMethods](https://www.softwareag.com/jp/products/webmethods_integration/integration/integration_server/default); it was an independent company until it was bought by Software AG.